# Где ошибка в запрос и в коде?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Есть бд и таблица. В ней записано много значений.

Мне нужно, чтобы вывелись все значения таблицы в формате json и еще дополнительное условие , если строки одинаковые(но параметр cost разный, то вывести наибольшее из них).

Вот мой код.

```
mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$date = array();
$row = mysql_query("SELECT sh,name,ed,MAX(cost) AS cost FROM 'datatable'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row){
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

?>

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 5):

Дело в агрегирующей функции max(), с ней надо использовать группировку.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос.

Comment: @MartinezToni, очень интересно, какой же вам нужен ответ? При использовании max, данные нужно группировать (group by), а я не телепат, чтобы понять по какому полю там надо группировать.

Comment: @MartinezToni `GROUP BY 'name'`